# C#JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, highcharts

I'm trying out the [HighStock library](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) for creating stock charts. To fill the chart with data, their example specifies [this source](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=goog-c.json&callback=?). The first parameter is unixtime in milliseconds and the second parameter is the stock closing price. I don't know if this is valid json, but I would argue that the following would be a more appropriate way of writing json.

```
[{"Closing":63.15000,"Date":1262559600000},{"Closing":64.75000,"Date":1262646000000}, ...
```

I guess that I have no other option than to adapt to HighStocks syntax. I could solve this by looping and add correct syntax to a string, but that seems rudimentary. Would it be more wise to serialize C# objects to create my json, and if that's the case - how can I reach the syntax specified in the example?

Lets just say this is my c# object:

```
public class Quote {
  public double Date { get; set; }
  public decimal Closing { get; set; }
}
```

Am I making it unnecessary complex? Should I just format a json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format they are looking for is valid json.  It's an array of arrays.

```
var item1 = new[] { 1, 2 };
var item2 = new[] { 3, 4 };
var itemArray = new[] { item1, item2 };
```

`itemArray` would serialize to `[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]`.

You should be able to keep your existing class and just make it a serialization concern.

For example, in an mvc app you could have:

```
public ActionResult Quotes() { 
    var quotes = service.GetQuotes(); //IEnumerable<Quote>
    return Json(quotes.Select(x=>new[] { EpochMillis(x.Date), (double)x.Closing }).ToArray());
}

private double EpochMillis(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first look, i would say, replace the { } by [ ] to get the base format. Afterwards you probably could remove the Labels (of your valid JSON) to get the final result.

I wouldn't recommend to use a library which is not supporting the official json standard at all...

Try other libs like Infragistics or C1 - they are quite good!

Greetings,

Comment: Okay... but serialize -> string replace -> output seems like an almost equally bad solution... perhaps. However, I don't like it.

Comment: Of course you don't like that. It's a bad and less quality way to do it. Library developer should always support official standards and not something "homebrewn..."

Comment: Yes, you are correct... it's a good thing that they support standards.

Comment: Mario - The json they are asking for is valid.  It's an array of arrays.